# jQuery event on responsed data from server

Tags: jquery, ajax, events

I have some content from server using $.ajax() function. I try to replace some element with this data and then manipulate it. Here is code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "smpl.php",
    success: function(servmsg){
        $('#panelInfo').replaceWith('<p>' + servmsg + '</p>');
    }
});
```

response from server is:

```
<select id="years">
    <option>2008</option>
    <option>2009</option>
</select>
```

when I try some event on it, it's doing nothing, for ex:

```
$('#years').change(function() { //or .click()
    //do something
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change your code to:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "smpl.php",
    success: function(servmsg){
        $('#panelInfo').replaceWith('<p>' + servmsg + '</p>');
        $('#years').change(function() { //or .click()
            //do something
        });
    }
});
```

Alternately, you could keep your original ajax call code, and use [livequery](http://brandonaaron.net/docs/livequery/) like so:

```
$('#years').livequery('change', function() { //or .click()
    //do something
});
```

Then when you inserted the #years block, it'd have the `change` event automatically registered.

Answer (score 0):

The event binding code should be inside the 'success' function, so it will run after #years is added to the page. Otherwise, jquery is looking for #years and cannot find it, and no binding is made.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use jquery 1.3 (release today) then look into the new .live() method.